# Issue in reading XML file in Excel 2010

Tags: xml, excel, vba

I wrote this code to open XSL file in Excel 2003, but this code is working fine for 2003 not for 2010. What should I replace this code with the code compatible to 2010?

Here is the code:

```
Sub test()
Dim fs As FileSearch
Dim i As Integer
Dim wbk As Workbook

Set fs = Application.FileSearch

With fs
    .LookIn = ThisWorkbook.Path
    .Filename = "*.xsl"
    For i = 1 To .Execute()
        Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(.FoundFiles(i))
        wbkname = ActiveWorkbook.Name


' Selecting the name of site and the tenent operators
    Range("A65536:Z65536").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
    Pr = Selection.Row
    Range("A1" & ":" & "Z" & Pr).Select
    Selection.Copy


    Windows("1 macro.xls").Activate
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("A65536").Select
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Windows(wbkname).Activate
     wbk.Close SaveChanges:=False

Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You're trying to load an `XML Stylesheet` into Excel as if it were a data-set?  Or is that an XML file with an odd extension?

Comment: `Application.FileSearch` doesn't exist in Excel 2007/2010. You can use `Dir()` to do what you need.

Comment: Looks like various people helped format this and trim the begging, but this was reverted without a good reason being supplied. Please don't do this! Downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

Excel natively has far, FAR better XML handling capabilities than VBA without MSXML.  Read up on the [XML Mapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg469857.aspx) feature.